# Google chart add another chart next to each other

Tags: php, html, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I made a working chart with mysql and I want to make another chart next to my 1st chart but it does not go well.

my code

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>
 1234
 </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

///Start Chart
 ['Date', 'Total Orders'],
 <?php 
 $query = "SELECT count(totalExcl) AS count, saleType FROM ps_oxoquotation_quotation WHERE date_add >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY saleType";

 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['saleType']."',".$row['count']."],";
 }
 ?>
 ///End Chart

 ]);

 var options = {
 title: 'Total Orders in 2017'
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>1234</h3>
 <div id="columnchart" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my chart but i want to make another one next to each other:

[image]

Comment: External images are not great for SO; they will disappear one day. Also, what have tried in order to solve this yourself?

Comment: I did copy from ///start chart till ///end chart and pasted it after ///End chart but it did not work it gave me a blank page.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you can't put raw PHP markup in the question text and expect it to be rendered. Even if it could be rendered, how would you expect it to find the data? You can place the image inline.

Comment: To clarify, you want to render a similar type of chart next to this one? That is, you want to have some PHP markup along with the existing PHP markup that renders charts horizontally? Or something else? You should be clear **in the body of the question** what your end goal is, and how you tried to achieve this. That is, no one is going to write your markup for you.

Comment: I just want to add the same chart with another sql tabel next to this one. But when i copy from ///start chart till ///end chart and pasted it after ///End chart it gave me a blank page.

Comment: Please put details like this **in the body of the question text**. What have you tried? You can add borders and separators in the CSS or HTML mark to see where things are being rendered. You can inspect the source in the browser to see if the PHP ran, and what it rendered. You can inspect server logs to see if something is being reported. You could read the Google docs for the arrayToDataTable() method to see if it has ways of debugging/inspecting. Clearly this is not a plain markup issue because you are depending on a Google visualization API of some sort.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that arrayToDataTable() can accept two chunks of PHP? I suspect it accepts, at most, a single array of data. You probably want two sets of visualization data, which is then drawn later. But I don't know Google Visualization API so you are going to have to read the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

highly recommend **not** mixing *php* within *html / javascript*...

instead, use *php* to return the data in *json* format...

**getdata1.php**

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT count(totalExcl) AS count, saleType FROM ps_oxoquotation_quotation WHERE date_add >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY saleType";
  $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();

  $table['cols'] = array(
      array('label' => 'Sale Type', 'type' => 'string'),
      array('label' => 'Total Orders', 'type' => 'number')
  );

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['saleType']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['count']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
  }

  $table['rows'] = $rows;

  echo json_encode($table);
?>
```

then use *jquery / ajax* to get the data from *php* and draw the chart...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
      // draw chart from php data
      $.ajax({
        url: 'getdata1.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (jsonData) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          var options = {
            title: 'Total Orders in 2017'
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown + ': ' + textStatus);
        }
      });

      // then just use another php page to get the other data and draw another chart
      $.ajax({
        url: 'getdata2.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (jsonData) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          var options = {
            title: 'Total Other Orders in 2017'
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart2"));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown + ': ' + textStatus);
        }
      });
    },
    packages: ['corechart']
  });
</script>
```

---

**note**, also recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, vs. `jsapi`

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.