# Drawing google multi line chart via php (problems about php JSON format)

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a google line chart with multiple line by using php.

I got the following data from my database:

```
region Month Total
 JP     12     1
 US     12     1
 JP      1     2
 US      1     1
 CN      2     4
 DE      2     3
 JP      2     4
 RU      2     5
 US      2     4
```

Refer to google chart official website:

```
   function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

  data.addRows([
    [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
    [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
    [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
    [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
    [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
    [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
  ]);
```

How do i populate my data to the above format at php? For example:

```
    function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', 'JP');
  data.addColumn('number', 'US');
  data.addColumn('number', 'RU');
  data.addColumn('number', 'CN');
  data.addColumn('number', 'DE');

  data.addRows([
    [12,  1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1,  2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [2,  4, 4, 5, 4, 3],
  ]);
```

i got the php code currently (encode to json part):

```
$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

$array = array();
$array['cols'][] = array('label' => 'Month','type' => 'string', 'Month');

for ($i=1; $i<($rowCount+1); $i++){
  $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $array['cols'][] = array('label' => $result['region'],'type' => 'number', 'Record per month');
  $array['rows'][]['c'] = array(
      array('v' => $result['Month'] ),
      array('v' => $result['Total'] )
  ); 
}
```

And it gave me :

```
{  
"cols":[  
  {  
     "label":"Month",
     "type":"string",
     "0":"Month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"JP",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"US",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"JP",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"US",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"CN",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"DE",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"JP",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"RU",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  },
  {  
     "label":"US",
     "type":"number",
     "0":"Record per month"
  }
 ],
 "rows":[  
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"12"
        },
        {  
           "v":"1"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"12"
        },
        {  
           "v":"1"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"1"
        },
        {  
           "v":"2"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"1"
        },
        {  
           "v":"1"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"2"
        },
        {  
           "v":"4"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"2"
        },
        {  
           "v":"3"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"2"
        },
        {  
           "v":"4"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"2"
        },
        {  
           "v":"5"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "c":[  
        {  
           "v":"2"
        },
        {  
           "v":"4"
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: My question is about fitting the data into the correct json format

Answer (score 0):

once you have the *json* data, you can create the google `DataTable` directly,

no need to add columns or rows (those are already defined in the *json*)...

```
var googleData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = {
    "cols":[
      {
         "label":"Month",
         "type":"string",
         "0":"Month"
      },
      {
         "label":"JP",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"US",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"JP",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"US",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"CN",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"DE",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"JP",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"RU",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      },
      {
         "label":"US",
         "type":"number",
         "0":"Record per month"
      }
     ],
     "rows":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"12"
            },
            {
               "v":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"12"
            },
            {
               "v":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"1"
            },
            {
               "v":"2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"1"
            },
            {
               "v":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2"
            },
            {
               "v":"4"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2"
            },
            {
               "v":"3"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2"
            },
            {
               "v":"4"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2"
            },
            {
               "v":"5"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"2"
            },
            {
               "v":"4"
            }
         ]
      }
     ]
  };

  var googleData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(googleData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: it appears the json data, posted in the question, is missing values for columns 3 thru 6...

Comment: hello, I'm asking about how to fit my data into the correct json format

Comment: looks good to me, and obviously works above, just need to add additional column values to each row --> `"c":[{"v":"2"}, {"v":"4"}]` -- should look more like --> `"c":[{"v":"2"}, {"v":"4"}, {"v":"4"}, {"v":"4"}, {"v":"4"}, {"v":"4"}]`...

Comment: if you need help getting the data to the page, use ajax - check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42239015/5090771)...